# Andengine Box2D physics body is not rotating when increase weight

Tags: android, box2d, andengine, game-physics

Andengine Box2D physics body is not rotating when increase weight otherwise its perfectly rotating.I am making a game in which the  player can throw the bomb, when the player throws the  bomb with bombsBody's natural weight its rotating perfectly but when i increase the weight of bomb the bomb does not rotate.i m stuck here..plz help.
Thank you.

```
if (bomb)           
{
    mScene.detachChild(target);
    target = null;      
    bombFire = new Sprite(mBall2.getX()+mBall2.getWidth()/2,mBall2.getY(),bombFireRegion);
    mScene.attachChild(bombFire);
    bombBody = PhysicsFactory.createCircleBody(mPhysicsWorld, bombFire,BodyType.DynamicBody, bombFixDef);
    bombBody.setMassData(bombMass);
    mPhysicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(bombFire, bombBody, true, true));               
    Vector2 v = new Vector2((xpt-mBall2.getX()),(ypt-mBall2.getY()));
    bombBody.applyLinearImpulse(v,bombBody.getWorldCenter());
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest.Above is the code..

Comment: Thanks. What values are in the variable 'bombMass'? Maybe you are setting the rotational inertia to zero.

Comment: MassData bombMass=new MassData();  bombMass.mass=10f;

Comment: Thank you very much iforce2d i set the rotational inertia equal to 1, its working..(bomb is rotating perfectly) :)

Answer (score 5):

Changing the mass of an existing body is best done by scaling the existing massData of that body. This keeps the center of mass in the right place and also ensures that the mass and rotational inertia match correctly.

```
b2MassData massData;
body->GetMassData(&massData);

float scaleFactor = desiredMass / massData.mass;
massData.mass *= scaleFactor;
massData.I *= scaleFactor;

body->SetMassData(&massData);
```

One thing to be aware of is that this does not affect the density of the fixtures on the body. If you add or remove any fixtures from the body after this, the mass data will be recalculated from the fixtures, not from your mass data. So you would have to do this again after changing fixtures to restore your desired mass.